# tensile-kube unable to get log from provider

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using tensile-kube to setup a labs cluster with 1 upper-node and link to 2 provider

I can create pod, secret, pvc, ... but when calling logs, it just fail

```
root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl logs nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n 
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n)
```

on the upper node

```
root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n   1/1     Running            0          18m   10.244.71.14   192.168.122.212   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-fwwzb   1/1     Running            0          50m   10.244.71.11   192.168.122.212   <none>           <none>
```

on the provider:

```
root@tensile-kube-master-lower1:~# kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n   1/1     Running            0          19m   10.244.71.14   tensile-kube-worker-lower1   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-fwwzb   1/1     Running            0          51m   10.244.71.11   tensile-kube-worker-lower1   <none>           <none>
```

So anyone have ever use tensile-kube and get logs from provider pod ?

---

## UPDATE #1:

I have create another user with `ClusterRole` access to pod, but not it's logs:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-10-10T03:13:16Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:rules: {}
    manager: kubectl-edit
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-10-10T03:18:18Z"
  name: readonlyuser
  resourceVersion: "54949"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/readonlyuser
  uid: 237b02e7-cf30-4fe2-8234-241d49ae12c0
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/log
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

I use that user-context and problems still the same

```
root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl config use-context podreader
Switched to context "podreader".

root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl get pod
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n   1/1     Running            1          18h
nginx-deployment-764c5ccb79-xms6q   1/2     ImagePullBackOff   1          19h

root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl logs nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n)
root@tensible-kube-master:~# kubectl exec -it nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n /bin/bash
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dxc2n" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:readonlyuser" cannot create resource "pods/exec" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

Comment: Based on that behavior, I would guess the `ClusterRoleBinding` for the `user:` in your kubeconfig forbids accessing the `pods/log` resource, either at all or for that namespace

Comment: Hmm, in that case, my only other theory is a kubectl version mismatch, since they have weird error messages when the client and the server versions drift out of sync; can you include the output of `kubectl version`?